# Spring support for MIME type "multipart/byteranges"

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, http, multipart

I have following controller API:

```
@GetMapping(produces = "multipart/byteranges")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getMultipartContent() {
        MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
        builder.part("name", "Jhon").header("custom-header", "headerValue");

        builder.part("bitOfFileContent", Arrays.copyOf("abcdefghijklmnop".getBytes(), 11), MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
                .header("file", "file1.txt").header(HttpHeaders.RANGE, "0-10");

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(builder.build());
    }
```

Here I want to return response with content type "multipart/byteranges". 
But I am get following exception:

```
2020-01-01 12:16:02.841  WARN 18904 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

I am using Spring boot 2.2.2.RELEASE.

Does Spring support MIME type "multipart/byteranges" ?

If not, what could be the alternative for this?

Can I use "multipart/mixed" instead ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

dealing with file and form the MIME type would be `multipart/form-data` try with this it might work

```
@GetMapping(produces = "multipart/form-data")
```